# How do I remove the application icon from the top panel?

Tags: gnome

I started using Gnome Shell 3.2 today and I think the topbar can be a little bit better. I want to know if this is possible to make and, if possible, how I make it:

This is how is now:

[image]

This is how I think is better:

[image]

It 'just' remove the icon above the app name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/path/to/your/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css`
(default path is `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/` )

Find there something simmilar to this: (it's on lines 3xx-4xx)

```
.panel-button #appMenuIcon {
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
}

.panel-button #appMenuIcon {
    app-icon-bottom-clip: 0px;
}

.panel-button:active #appMenuIcon,
.panel-button:checked #appMenuIcon,
.panel-button:focus #appMenuIcon {
    app-icon-bottom-clip: 0px;
}

.app-menu-icon {
   /* width: 24px;
    height: 24px; */
}
```

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> -> r

That should remove the icon.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can install ["Elegance Colors"](https://github.com/satya164/elegance-colors) which holds the option for hiding the App-icon.

You only need to install it and uncheck the App Icon slider:

[image]

On this note I want to know why my other question was removed, I looked up the requirements in the help center and non of them applied, it was a different way and most importantly easier.