# Remove app icon from title bar in GNOME in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, gnome-shell, titlebar

I'm trying to hide the app icon from the title bar in GNOME in Ubuntu 18.04. I know there is [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71722/how-do-i-remove-the-application-icon-from-the-top-panel) asking the same thing but it's from 2011 and I can't find what it requires to find in the shell css. I'm also using the Arc-Dark custom theme.

Here are two examples of what I want to remove:

[image: example1]

[image: example2]

To be clear, I don't want to resize it to fit, I want to straight away remove it completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launch *(GNOME) Tweaks* and go to the "**Top Bar**" section. Then toggle on the "*Application Menu*" option.

[image]