# Terminal Icon larger than should be (out of border) - Ubuntu 18

Tags: gnome, icons, gnome-terminal, interface, titlebar

I'm new to Ubuntu. Very strange and annoying thing happened. Terminal  (only) icon larger than it should be and out of windows border. How can I fix that? GNOME tweaks is installed.
[image: Terminal window looks like this]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Terminal icon in window titlebar is stretched out over window control buttons](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974687/terminal-icon-in-window-titlebar-is-stretched-out-over-window-control-buttons). Also you can remove the icon altogether: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074625/remove-app-icon-from-title-bar-in-gnome-in-ubuntu-18-04